# How Can I Disable AutoSuggestions Through Android Manifest File?

Tags: android, twitter, webview, scribe

I am using Twitter Login in my android app and I would like to disable the auto-suggestions when a user is trying to type their username (during the Twitter login process).

It would be easy if I created the form fields myself since I could just set the inputType attribute to no suggestions in the xml file.

So, is there a way to achieve this result inside the AndroidManifest.xml file so that I can disable it for the entire activity handling Twitter Login?

Thanks in advance and let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable auto suggestion of input fields simply like this in webview

```
 webview.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
```

As I discussed with you [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/15198617#15198617), you can not disable the auto suggestion of keyboard from the android code programmatically in webview so for this either update your html file or disable your keyboard auto suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. I have disabled the keyboard settings but still does not fix it.

Comment: How did you, Can you write the steps which you did ?

Comment: Settings -> Language&input ->Android Keyboard ->Dynamic Floating Preview (unchecked), Enable Gesture Typing (unchecked), Auto-Correction (unchecked)Next word suggestion (unchecked)

Comment: I don't know how can you off text prediction in your device, search the settings on google how to off text prediction as per your device